# asyncData() reached in dev, not when published

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt application trying to put a facebook-share button on my dynamic data page. The page has to load some data with axios and update my meta data with the information.

It works in development but not when published ( universal app ).
I can also see in when the app is deployed, it loads my startpage and then goes to the route /profile/:id.

Nuxt states it only does the AsyncData() once when fetching the first page.
So how do i prevent it from going tot he other page first?

I tried adding the route in the nuxt.config.js
I can go to the page but the data does not load ( i think because the AsyncData() is not fired )

My dynamic route is: pages/profile/_id/index.vue
(tried with pages/profile/_id.vue had the same issue)

nuxt.config.js

```
router:{
    routes:[
      {
        name: 'profile-id',
        path: '/profile/:id?',
        component: 'pages/profile/_id.vue'
      }
    ]
  },
```

_id/index.vue

```
async asyncData({ app, params, store, }){
    var oets = await store.dispatch('profiles/getProfile', params.id )
     return {
       profile:{
         ...oets
       }
     }
  },
```

I added an input on my index page, with a search.
I send the param to the page -> this works.

```
this.$router.push(`profile/${this.search}`)
```

When the profile/id loads this way, it shows the data.
But ofcourse this does not help me to be a 'sharable' page with facebook.
When i crawl the site with facebook it returns the info from the 1st index page.
not the profile/id page.

Recap:
Works in dev, not in live
Seems to skip the AsyncData() function
I think I need some configuration altered or a different approach

Comment: Asyncdata work both in Dev and prod.it work only for page. And it's called either on server on client not both.

Comment: Can you help? How do i serve the dynamic page, with the data already loaded on?

Comment: i dont really understand what the problem. Are u using generate mode maybe?

Comment: Yes, when i use build it does not create a dist folder? please tell me more. How do i get my dist folder with npm run build?

Comment: And it shouldn't . Build is for ssr mode when u run node server in production that will serve requests.

Comment: Dist only created for generate and then for dynamic routes read this https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-generate#routes

Comment: I need to have it SSR not generate static so thank you for that!
So i did the firebase deploy with function and all.
Now when i go to the dynamic path directly it says: Cannot GET /profile/36 what's missing?

Comment: not familiar with firebase, but is it running a node process for each request that will do? or it just server static html file?